# SQL Server 2000 Group By asking for aggregate function when it is supplied

Tags: sql

I must be missing something obvious but why does the following

```
SELECT     c.ContractID, max( cs.ContractStatusCreated)
FROM       dbo.NMPT_Contract AS c INNER JOIN
           dbo.NMPT_ContractStatus AS cs ON c.ContractID = cs.ContractID INNER JOIN
           dbo.CMSS_Status AS s ON cs.StatusID = s.StatusID
group by  c.ContractID
having cs.ContractStatusCreated = MAX(cs.ContractStatusCreated)
```

return the following from SQL Server 2000?

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'cs.ContractStatusCreated'
>   is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either
>   an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Isn't `MAX` an aggregate function?

Comment: But it's not within `MAX` on the *left hand side* of that equals sign. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: When there error message says it is not contained in EITHER an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Doesn't that mean it needs to be just in one.

Comment: Yes, but it is in neither! (`... cs.ContractStatusCreated = ...`)

Comment: what would work is: having MAX(cs.ContractStatusCreated) > 1 (for example). In either case, it looks like "having" clause is not needed in your query; the result already produces max(Status) per ContractId

Comment: I was trying to retrieve the most recent status, I actually had it working with a subquery but i was trying to see if i could get it working with groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `cs.ContractStatusCreated` is not in the group-by clause, therefore it does not know where to get the data from.

And better yet, if you were to group by it you would end up with a `HAVING 1=1` condition and your `max(cs.ContractStatusCreated)` wouldn't do what you want. I think you need a self-join or subquery to find your max value to compare to.

Comment: I think this answer is slightly better as it mentioned the subquery. I was confused since i thought that MAX(cs.ContractStatusCreated) was putting cs.ContractStatusCreated in an agregate.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'cs.ContractStatusCreated' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function **or the GROUP BY clause**.

MAX is aggregate function

But ContractStatusCreated is NOT in the Group By

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked this but you could write your 'max' into a subquery something like this:

```
select     ContractID, ContractStatusCreated
FROM       dbo.NMPT_Contract AS x INNER JOIN            
           dbo.NMPT_ContractStatus AS y ON x.ContractID = y.ContractID
where (x.ContractID, y.ContractStatusCreated) = (
    SELECT     c.ContractID, max( cs.ContractStatusCreated) 
    FROM       dbo.NMPT_Contract AS c INNER JOIN            
               dbo.NMPT_ContractStatus AS cs ON c.ContractID = cs.ContractID INNER JOIN            
               dbo.CMSS_Status AS s ON cs.StatusID = s.StatusID 
    group by  c.ContractID
)
```